# Run Click JavaScript AFTER Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to run a JavaScript code on a button AFTER it is validated and clicked.  I can get the code to run without any validation, but when I added the "if valid" in line 2, the JavaScript will not run at all and the form will not submit.

Here is the JS which works CORRECTLY except it runs everytime you click the button.  I want to run it only when the form is valid.

```
<script>        
$('.subscribe-form-submit').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after('<input type="button" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subscribe-form-submit" value="Thanks!" />');
        return true;
        }
);
</script>
```

I attempted to add an if valid selector, but then the form does not submit at all and the JS does not run:

```
<script>
    $('.subscribe-form-submit').click(function(){
    if($('_form_1228').valid()) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after('<input type="button" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary subscribe-form-submit" value="Thanks!" />');
        return true;
        }
});
</script>
```

Here is my form, but I believe the only info you need from it is that the ID is "_form_1228".

```
<form action='excluded' method='post' id='_form_1228' class="subscribe-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s" role="form" accept-charset='utf-8' enctype='multipart/form-data' target="_blank">
<div class="form-validation alert"><!-- Validation Message here --></div>
<div class="form-group subscribe-form-input">
    <input type='hidden' name='f' value='1228'>
    <input type='hidden' name='s' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='c' value='0'>
    <input type='hidden' name='m' value='0'>
    <input type='hidden' name='act' value='sub'>
    <input type='hidden' name='nlbox[]' value='20'>
    <div id='compile999'>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-form-email form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your email address" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>  
    <div id='_field1000'>
        <div id='compile1000'>
            <button class="subscribe-form-submit btn btn-black btn-lg" type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Subscribe</button>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your JS is trying to validate a tag named `_form_1228`, instead of the form with `id=_form_1228`. Your selector should be `if ($('#_form_1228').valid()) {`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Posting a link to a site that will change over time will make this question unusable for future visitors. Instead, it's preferable to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a snippet.

Comment: Thanks @DrewGaynor I updated the code and removed a link to my website.

Comment: @PaulRoub Hi Paul.  I made your change but it did not work, any extra thoughts?  The button does not do anything when I click it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with your selectors...
See;

```
if($('_form_1228').valid()) {
```

should be;

```
if($('#_form_1228').valid()) {
```

Also this;

```
 if($this.hasClass('.subscribe-form-submit')){
```

should be:

```
 if($this.hasClass('subscribe-form-submit')){
```

To sum up, when you are selecting an element with jquery, you use . (dot) character on your classes, # (hash) on your element id's. But when you are checking if that element has a specific class with hasClass function, you shouldn't use . (dot) character at the beginning of your class name.

Comment: I made the change to the form id selector, and removed the actions I had using the hasClass, but it does not work.  Updated code above.  Any thoughts

Comment: are you sure that you have included the jquery validation plugin?